# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS no internet connection

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, virtualbox

I'm new to LinUX and it's my first time using an OS without a graphical interface (so excuse me if my problem is trivial or anything). I installed the 18.04 LTS version of Ubuntu LinUX on VirtualBox (using a Windows 10 laptop, if it matters), and unlocked the root account and assigned a password to it. I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YZDtfLzjS4) YouTube video, where it is recommended to update and then upgrade packages before doing anything else. However, when I enter the following error:

`sudo apt-get update` command, I get the following error:

```
Err:1 http:at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'at.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I then tried configuring the netplan file to resolve the connection issue by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlOY1ucz_DY) guide. That, however, didn't resolve the issue.

Also, when pinging myself, I get responses. But when pinging the gateway, or any other IP or domain name, I get the `Destination Host Unreachable` error.

Here is my netplan file from `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource. Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-confid.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses: [192.168.69.2/22]
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 192.168.69.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]
    version: 2
```

and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn128.png)'s the `ifconfig -a` response (was too lazy to type it in here...)

Any help at all will be MUUUCH appreciated. I've looked into almost every post/forum discussion on this subject and none of the suggestions have helped me resolve the issue and it's driving me crazy!

EDIT1:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alSKn.png)'s a screenshot of my virtual machine's details.

EDIT2: the 192.168.96.2/24 in the netplan file was a typo. The actual netplan file says 192.168.69.2/22

EDIT3: Okay, I know this sounds weird. I certainly find it weird. But after answering a few questions here and going to check why my netplan file showed a different netmask than `ifconfig -a`, I just randomly did the `apt-get update` thing again and... it worked? How can this be? Aren't computers and computer programs supposed to respond equally under equal circumstances? I have changed absolutely nothing in my configuration files. Oh but I would still like to know how you can solve this issue. It updated my packages, yes. But I still can't ping anything.

Comment: Why have you disabled dhcp?

Comment: You seem to have a typo there. Is it 192.168.96.xx or 192.168.69.xx? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `I'm new to LinUX and it's my first time using an OS without a graphical interface...` Hmm... you're a beginner? What are you aiming at? 1. Keeping DHCP enabled and allowing your router provide the "gory details" (do start the DHCP server/daemon) is the easy way. 2. no need to use the command line if you're new to it. You don't run a windows PC from cmd.exe, or even PowerShell. There is a difference though; You CAN do very much from the bash prompt, I believe it is a bit harder to do anything similar on a PC with the MS OS.

Comment: You have multiple strangeties in your post. `ifconfig` shows 192.168.69.2/22 as address. Your config shows 192.168.96.2/24 as address. Which way is it? And what adapter type have you selected in virtualbox? If it's NAT: does the configured settings in virtualbox match what you have defined in the config. If it's passthru (bridge): does it match your home network? I suggest sticking with DHCP...

Comment: @chili555 it's 192.168.69.xx. Sorry '^-^

Comment: @Hannu believe it or not, it's a school assignment. We're supposed to figure out how to start a LinUX Terminal Server and then implement it on a Raspberry Pi (a print server, a VPN server, a cloud server, etc.). Our assignment for the coming Tuesday is to install LinUX on a VM (I chose VirtualBox), set the server up, and secure an internet connection.

Comment: @vidarlo I edited the post and added a screenshot with my machine's details

Comment: @CubeMage You've not answered all my questions. How have you configured the network adapter in Virtualbox? Where did you get 192.168.69.0/24 from? Why does your config show 192.168.69.0/24, whilst `ifconfig` shows /22?

Comment: I haven't configured my network adapter. I just left it the way it was. It says "Adapter 1: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (Bridged Adapter, Realtek RTL8821C 802.11ac PCIe Adapter)". And 192.168.69 is a unique IP I made up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101427/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-cubemage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't configured my network adapter. I just left it the way it was. It says "Adapter 1: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (Bridged Adapter, Realtek RTL8821C 802.11ac PCIe Adapter)". **And 192.168.69 is a unique IP I made up**.

You can't do that.

According to your question, the adapter is bridged. In this case, your configuration *has* to match the physical network that your host is connected to. If you move your host (or VM) to a different network, configuration will have to be updated to match the network it's connected to.

To find what network the host is, you can run `ipconfig` in cmd in windows. Note that questions about this is offtopic on AU, and I only include it to help you.

If you set your adapter to NAT, you will not have to update, and you can set the IP's more freely, as Virtualbox will translate for you. NAT has the drawback that you'll have to configure port forwarding to expose any services on the network the host is attached to. This is somewhat more hassle to keep updated, but the nice thing is that your VM will work everywhere, even with static configuration.

Furthermore, I see no reason not to stick with DHCP, in this case, and in general. If you need a static IP, make a reservation in DHCP, or even rely on DDNS to keep DNS in sync with DHCP scopes.

To use DHCP, edit your config to

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource. Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-confid.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the contents of `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` with the following

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses: [192.168.96.2/24]
            dhcp4: true
            gateway4: 192.168.96.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]
    version: 2
```

Now, restart the VM and run the following commands and post the output

```
ping 1.1.1.1
ping google.com
```

Comment: sorry, the 96 was a typo. I edited the original post to correct it. T_T